# What can be best view or way to Show MS SQL Table Records with Dynamic Column WIdths to auto resize?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, user-interface

I have a MS SQL Server Table like this
[image]

The Length of the addresses and name could vary, i want to dynamically adjust the width of columns according to the largest width column.
if their is any external library or view to manage that ot any other view that will help on my problem

I tried using normal recyclerView but it didn't work as expected

RecylerView Layout

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_0parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

RecyclerView Item Layout:

```
<!-- item_record.xml -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRollNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        style="@style/columns_style" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewfatherName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Java Method to detch and populate data to recyclerView:

```
        @Override
        protected List<Record> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
                Connection connect = connectionHelper.connectionClass();
                if (connect != null) {
                    String query = "SELECT * FROM class";
                    try (Statement st = connect.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            int rollNo = rs.getInt("rollno");
                            String name = rs.getString("name");
                            String fatherName = rs.getString("fathername");
                            String address = rs.getString("address");
                            String phoneNo = rs.getString("phoneno");

                            Record record = new Record(rollNo, name, fatherName, address, phoneNo);
                            records.add(record);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Error executing query", e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            return records;
        }
```

This is How my Table Activity is looks in the end
[image: here is the result]